# how to call a rest api using a bearer token in authorization header in secure way? Sample code c# please

Tags: api, caching, token, azure-api-management, rest

1. How to store the JWT Bearer token I obtain into my APIM. I obtain this token from an external provider outside of my network. I pass some client credential, client id, secret etc

I am thinking to do in inbound policy, is that the right place? Also how to set the time for expiry of cache? I am following this but it doesnt say where it has the time for expiry value but just variable I see. https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Backend%20OAuth2%20Authentication%20With%20Cache.policy.xml

2. a sample C# Code for calling the third party api through the obtained token above how do I do in APIm or service fabric please? I am new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to store the JWT Bearer token I obtain into my APIM.

As you have provided, you can use `<set-variable name="accessToken" value=""/>` to store access token.

> how to set the time for expiry of cache

The [`cache-store`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#StoreToCache) policy caches responses according to the specified cache settings. Set response cache duration using maxAge value in Cache-Control header sent by the backend.

```
<cache-store duration="seconds" />
```